# Alkylation before ring closure?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, amines

So, another question from my side.
I have been thinking about the folowing reaction:[image]

The reaction above exists and was already done on two occasions and reportedly works really well and it seems to be a no-brainer to me as well. Now, my question is related to the reaction below with the alkylated amine. First question: the alkylation of the compound above seems difficult, BECAUSE how can I make sure that I only alkylate the primary amine in meta position to the bromine? Can I use a protection group before for the other primary amine?

Second question: if the alkylation is possible as I imagine it here, can I still perform the reaction as depicted? Or is it unfavored because suddenly a positive charge appears?

Greetings

Comment: This shouldn't be much of a problem, but alkylated form would be probably better made using ethylamine in synthesis then alkylating diamine.

Comment: The ethylated material in the red box is accessible by SN2 on 4-Br-2-F-nitrobenzene with ethylamine followed by reduction of the nitro group. I think the condensation reaction to give the cationic species is viable